# Adding raw data to PE .text section in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, portable-executable, packer

I am currently working on a packer and I need to copy raw data in the section containing the code (. text), is there any way to do this in VC++ ?

If it's impossible, could you recommend me some good C/C++ lib to edit PE files ?

Comment: In some cases it is technically impossible to add extra data to already linked PE without risk to break it. And I guess there is no any library for such purpose.

Comment: http://re.coldwind.pl/dl/packer_005.zip

It can help

Comment: @Serhio could you please elaborate on 'technically impossible'? What are some cases that it would be so?

Comment: By the way @Omen these may be helpful: 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12532/Inject-your-code-to-a-Portable-Executable-file

http://coder.pub/2014/09/pe-file-packer-step-by-step-step-7-relocations/

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/33006-detailed-guide-to-pe-infection/?hl=%2Brelocation

http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile2.html

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/41510-another-detailed-guide-to-pe-infection/

Comment: @kubuzetto The simplest case is when there is no free virtual space between `.text` and subsequent section. It may be `.data` or something else. Assuming that we can not replace original `.text` content we have no way to append extra data, since virtual address of next section must be preserved and we can not move it.

Comment: Under what circumstances would we be unable to replace original `.text` content (except for an intentional tamper-proofing mechanism)?

Comment: Use `#pragma section(".text")` first, then `__declspec(allocate(".text")) unsigned char packedData[] = {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extend the `.text` section, adding a new executable section and injecting your code there might be a better solution. Then you put a `jmp` to the address from which you want to divert the execution (which will overwrite some of the instructions there), start your code with the overwritten instructions and continue to whatever you wanted to do, then return to the original execution with another jump. Note that if the overwritten code also contains addresses/relocations, these should also be updated properly.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this solution, but adding a new executable section is basically asking any AV to flag you as a malware.

Comment: I see your point now. I don't think I have come across a solution for it, though.